Stuck Bitcoin Core Wallet can't send out
I have a wallet from 2013 that has a fair amount in it I'd like to get to. I have it restored on bitcoin core on a few separate machines, each with a full node. When I made it I didn't put on a passphrase but it now asks for when when I try to make a transaction. On one machine only it will not ask for a passphrase if I go through Bitcoin CLI.
I also can't get it to give the private key so that I can import it to electrum. It will either ask for a passphrase or it will say that there isn't a private key known. When I do a dumpwallet I can't seem to find the right private key to import to electrum. I might just not know which so any help with that would be appreciated.
When looking at the transaction to rebroadcast them it says that they have bad-txns-nonstandard-inputs (code -26). This may be due to some dust, the lowest amount I have on a singular input is 868 sats. I've tried to sendmany to conjoin it but when I do it tells me that there is a JSON parsing error. sendmany "" {"walletaddress": amountofdust} It tells me similar when I try to specify the input for a transaction it tells me similar.
Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you.
